# WPF Shell Dimming background when popup opens combobox but control (togglebutton) also gets dimmed

Tags: wpf, shell, combobox, wpf-controls, prism

Using PRISM in WPF application, I am having a shell with a Border with a background color and alpha level to such that it looks semi-transparent and gives a feeling that background is dimmed.

This action I am wiring up with Combobox inside one of my modules and when its popup opens, it should send signal to shell saying to toggle visibility of dim effect we just created above.

PROBLEM: The combobox Popup get focus when it is open and is not dimmed as it just opened on top order. But the toggle button underlying got dimmed as well. Although it has focus and I can type (since it is editable combobox box).

What could I do to resolve this requirement. ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you want to be not dimmed? the popup, the combobox itself or both? I guess you'll need some kind of custom combobox that includes a copy of the editbox in the popup and syncs the input to the original one.

Comment: I want the Combobox (Main Toggle button) not to be dimmed. 

Partial Solution : I got this working by Panel.Zindex="1" and it works. The combobox completely now stands out in the z order. But 

Problem still remains: I have Custom WPF Templated Control where I have similar setup and if I apply Panel.Zindex to 1 or 99 or whatever, it does not work and stand out. 

I am not complete motivated to do it the suggestion you are saying that to include the copy of editbox in the popup. I strongly feel there will be a straightforward tricky way.

Thanks for your suggestion though @Haukinger

Answer (score 0):

Ok luckily Its a quick fix after posting this question. 
I applied Panel.Zindex to 1 on Combobox control and its working. Its not dimming the control anymore.

Please note:

Whenever you apply Zindex to 1 and feel its not rendering your control on top is because:
1. We may treat the panel.zindex as not attached property. 
2. Even if we apply correctly we forget that Visual tree has lot of parent panel. So if its set to 1 it may be rendering on top out of all other controls in that panel. But the immediate parent panel for that control will be still rendered behind the other controls on top.
3. So please observe and set all panel in its line to be the topmost. This also means you may need to change the layout and selection of controls OR control the zindex programatically.

Happy Coding.!